# Android Library for validating values

Tags: java, android, validation, saripaar

I'm using Validation library called **Android Saripaar v2**

link => 
https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar

It has some features like this

```
    @NotEmpty // this line does the magic
    @BindView(R.id.saveTextButton)
    TextView saveTextButton;
```

// note that `@BindView` is from Butterknife

it works just fine, but i can only use this for validating ui elements, not simple values, such like

```
boolean isUserPhotoSetted; // this should be true
```

the approach that i'm taking currently is to add a different block that handles only boolean validation with `if` statement.

i believe that something like this would be possible.

```
@ShouldBeTrue
boolean isUserPhotoSetted;

@MatchValue(true)
boolean isUserPhotoSetted;
```

same content in link below.
https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/issues/200

would there be any libraries to do something like this??

Comment: I don't know any, but I had to flag this since asking for libraries is off-topic

Comment: what do you need annotation for? is `if (isSelected)` not good enough

Comment: 5~10 `if`seems dirty for me..